# Azure pipline nuget failure

Tags: azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

Azure pipeline build.
summary:
nuget log says got EntityFrameworks
compiler says couldn't find it
it's not found in nuget packages path

Here is the YAML I used

```
task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
```

then I tried

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'DotNetCore Restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

The nuget log seems to say EntityFrameworks was installed.

Installed EntityFramework 6.4.4 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash.....
Checking compatibility for EntityFramework 6.4.4 with net6.0.
All packages and projects are compatible with net6.0.

however, when I check the folder using

```
powershell: |
   Write-Host "Show all nuget folder content"
   Get-ChildItem -Path $(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\*.* -Recurse -Force
  errorActionPreference: continue
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script List nuget folder structure'
  continueOnError: true
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

in the log I search for: entityframework
I get: No results

the compile fails

##[error]SingleVentricle_Model\Models\SingleVentricle.Context.cs(13,23): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

the project compiles and runs locally.

What am I missing? why isn't EntityFrameworks there?